# Popup page without internet connection using coova-chilli

Tags: wireless-networking, openwrt, popups

I am using **openwrt and coovachilli** for registration purpose, when there is presence of internet connection to router then chilli starts and **popup page** appears after connect to WiFi.
 But I want **popup page** without presence of internet. Router should popup after connect to WiFi using **coovachilli** without **internet**. Please help me out in this situation.
Thanks in advance.

OpenWrt Version:- 15.05
CoovaChilli Version:- 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

you need a local dns

add 2 zones into local DNS (bind server too resolves on UAMLISTEN IP, Port UDP 53)

Example:

HS_UAMLISTEN=10.10.10.1

HS_DNS1=10.10.10.1

Windows 10 and above use http://www.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt

Windows 8.1 and earlier versions use http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt

zone: msftncsi.com

www IN A 190.46.255.40 (or any public IP)

zone: msftconnecttest.com

www IN A 13.107.4.52 (or any public IP)

---

Another and best option, uses RPZ (Response Policy Zones)

in local zone:

response-policy { zone "rpz"; } qname-wait-recurse no;

zone "rpz" {

type master;

file "/etc/bind/db.rpz";

};

file db.rpz:

www.msftconnecttest.com         IN      A       13.107.4.52

www.msftncsi.com                IN      A       190.46.255.40

190.46.255.40 and 13.107.4.52 are the real IP addresses of each URL. It does not matter that you do not have internet, since coovachilli before login always responds to TCP ports 80 for any IP (not dropped on a Firewall or IPTABLES)

In this way the DNS resolves the hosts and the browser redirects the page.

Windows 10 it works perfect.

For Android devices:

connectivitycheck.gstatic.com   IN      A       216.58.222.163

connectivitycheck.android.com   IN      A       216.58.222.174

clients1.google.com             IN      A       216.58.222.174

clients3.google.com             IN      A       216.58.222.174

I have scrips that check the status of the internet, so when there is no connection it redirects to an "internet temporarily out of service" page. The captive portal also has several interventions according to the needs of my clients.

https://github.com/coova/coova-chilli/issues/212